# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'slice' IE8 MVC

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, jquery-jtable

I am using `JTable` for one of my `MVC` projects and facing a problem in edit functionality. Whenever I click on Save button on Edit window, I am getting `Js` error -- Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method `slice` and the modal window is not closing. Could anyone please help me to get rid of this problem.

By the way, the issue is seen in IE8, it is working like a champ in IE9.

jQuery version - 1.7.2

jQuery UI version - 1.8.20

jTable version - 2.1 (Latest version)

Comment: What is the object you're trying to `slice`.  It sounds like whatever code you're using is trying to run `slice` on an object that doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, please refer to [jTable's Issue #166: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'slice' + IE8](https://github.com/hikalkan/jtable/issues/166).